# Subversion prompts for username and password

Tags: svn, passwords, debian, credentials

In the course of a software installation, a version control tool called [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) has to be used:

```
mkdir ~/mm
cd ~/mm
svn co https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/micromanager2/trunk/ micro-manager1.4
svn co https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/
```

I'm a bit lost as to what is being done here, but a password and username is being prompted:

```
$ svn co https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/micromanager2/trunk/ micro-manager1.4
Authentication realm: <https://valelab4.ucsf.edu:443> Micro-Manager Subversion repository
Password for 'user':
```

When I just keep hitting *Enter*, I get the following:

```
Authentication realm: <https://valelab4.ucsf.edu:443> Micro-Manager Subversion repository
Username: 
Password for '': 

Authentication realm: <https://valelab4.ucsf.edu:443> Micro-Manager Subversion repository
Username: 
Password for '': 

svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

Does anyone know what happens here, what credentials are required and for what purpose?

Comment: i'm voting to close this, as it isn't about programming. if you are having trouble with a given product, you should probably contact their support.

Comment: There are countless questions like this, here on StackOverflow, and they are being discussed *right now*: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subversion - Want to close all of them? If not, then why this particular one and not another? You may, of course, point me to an alternative SE where this question might fit in better.

Comment: the "given product" i was referring to is "Micro-Manager" not subversion. your trouble is, that the project is apparantly dead. your question is basically "what is the password for website foo", which is totally off-topic for [so]. (if there are similar questions, please point me to them so i can also vote to close them)

Comment: No, it's about Subversion and I don't understand what this password prompt even is. I will remove the Micro-Manager reference if you insist. Else, if you have an idea regarding the password, any hint would be welcome, thx

Comment: Reference removed, question is now more focused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- subversion is a tool that fetches data from a remote-server.
- the remote-server can be configured to grant access to everybody (typically read-only)
  or to limit access to authorized people using a username/password scheme
- the remote-server you are trying to access obviously has chosen to restrict access to authorized people.

  - in order to access it, you need a secret username/password combination
  - why the owners of the repository chose to protect its content with a password, only they can tell.

    - maybe because the code had legal issues.
    - maybe because they took down their public subversion server altogether (keeping it running for internal uses only)
    - best ask them directly.
  - the only people who can give you a valid username/password combination are the owners of the repository

to answer the underlying question ("how can i get the micro-manager microscope software", which btw would be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)),  a quick google search for "micro-manager microscope" yields a public and active git-repository hosted on GitHub https://github.com/micro-manager/micro-manager

Comment: So SVN was not prompting for my credentials, but it's access restriction to the remote files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: technically, it was of course *subversion* that asked for the credentials, as it found that it couldn't access the repository without them.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, could you please share some insights into why? the answer obviously helped the OP (as they accepted it) so it seems to have at least *some* merits. however, if you feel that it is inappropriate, a note explaining why you think so might help me improvie my future answers.